# c# get a specific element of a HashSet

Tags: c#, hashset

I want to get an element of a HashSet only if it contains a specific string in it. i tried
the code below, but i dont get anything... like no matching. but this cant happen cause the UnKnown counter is always 0.

```
if (!IsbnAuth.Contains(RecTitle))
{
    Unknown++;
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < IsbnAuth.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (IsbnAuth.ElementAt(i).Contains(RecTitle))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(IsbnAuth.ElementAt(i));
            //isbn = IsbnAuth.ElementAt(i).Substring(0, IsbnAuth.ElementAt(i).IndexOf("\t"));
            isbn = IsbnAuth.ElementAt(i).Split(' ')[0];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? the problem is not at the RecTitle cause even if it was just a single char instead, the result would be the same.
IsbnAuth is the HashSet.

EDIT: IsbnAuth declaration

```
    HashSet<String> IsbnAuth = new HashSet<String>();
    foreach (String line in IsbnAuthors)
    {
        IsbnAuth.Add(line.Trim());
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine(IsbnAuth.Count);
```

Comment: IMO this loop is not necesary. If HashSet.Contains return true, you can use element passed to this function. Try `if (!IsbnAuth.Contains(RecTitle))
{
    Unknown++;
}
else
{ isbn = RecTitle.Split(' ')[0]; }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the first problem:

```
if (!IsbnAuth.Contains(RecTitle))
{
    Unknown++;
}
```

That checks whether the set contains the *whole* string, as a complete element. It sounds like it doesn't.

I suspect you really want:

```
bool found = false;
foreach (String element in IsbnAuth)
{
    if (element.Contains(RecTitle))
    {
        isbn = element.Split(' ')[0];
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found)
{
    Unknown++;
}
```

Or even better:

```
string isbn = IsbnAuth.Where(x => x.Contains(RecTitle))
                      .Select(x => x.Split(' ')[0])
                      .FirstOrDefault();
if (isbn == null)
{
    Unknown++;
}
```

It's worth being aware that a `HashSet` is in a fundamentally unpredictable order - so if there are multiple matches here, you'll end up with an *arbitrary* result. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are storing mulitple informations held in one string in your Hastable. I would do it in that way:

```
public class Info
{
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

later in code:

```
List<Info> isbnAuth = new List<Info>();
foreach (String line in IsbnAuthors)      
{ 
    isbnAuth.Add(new Info { ISDN = line.Split(' ')[0], Title = line.Split(' ')[1] });
}
```

You can search an item like this:

```
var itemFound = isbnAuth.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Title == RecTitle);
if (itemFound != null)
{
    isbn = itemFound.ISBN;
}
```